# Are there any package for stratified bootstrap re-sampling for principal component analysis in R?

Tags: r, pca, bootstrap

1. It is possible to bootstrap principal component analysis (see package bootSVD)
2. It is possible to conduct stratified bootstrapping (see package boot, option strata).

However, is it possible to conduct stratified bootstrap resampling for principcal component analysis?

Specifically, I have a sample of 500. I would like to choose my sample size (rather than allow repetition) of 20 for each draw. I would also like to ensure that it is stratified along gender (10 males, 10 females). Is this possible in any existing package?

I know how to draw random samples and run the analysis in a loop but I am not sure that is valid to combine it with principal component analysis. Would it work to calculate the means of the factor loadings, z-scores, eigenvalues and present this as the final output?